# Semisimplicity of End$_{F[G]}(M)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and $G$ be a finite group. Let $M$ be a finitely generated free $F[G]$-module where $F[G]$ is the usual group ring.

Can anyone explain to me why the $F$-algebra End$_{F[G]}(M)$ is semisimple?

Comment: See what happens if $F$ and $G$ have size 2, and $M$ has rank 1.

Comment: I guess $F[G]$ would then be a simple ring so End($M$) semisimple. If $F[G]$ is semisimple (eg if char $F=0$) can we still say that End($M$) is semisimple?  Thanks

Comment: If F and G have size 2 and M has rank 1, then End(M) = Z[x]/(2,x^2) is not semisimple. If char F = 0, then yes, M is semisimple and its endomorphism ring are semisimple.

Comment: How you get End($M$)$=\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2,X^2)$ in the first case? Thanks

Comment: [Related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425914/is-a-semisimple-a-module-semisimple-over-its-endomorphism-ring/426099#426099) (but not a duplicate, as far as I can see).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Maschke's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem), $F[G]$ is a semisimple ring, and so $M$ is a semisimple $F[G]$ module. Since it is finitely generated, it is a direct sum of finitely many simple submodules.

If you know the ideas behind the [Artin-Wedderburn theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn-Artin_theorem) well, then you can derive that $M$ breaks into pieces, which breaks the endomorphism ring of $M$ into pieces. Since $M$ is finitely generated, each of the pieces that $End_{F[G]}(M)$ breaks into are simple Artinian rings.

(An alternative high level explanation is that the endomorphism ring of a semisimple module is always [von Neumann regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring), and if the module is f.g. then it is Artinian too, whence it is semisimple. But please keep reading if this blurb is not useful!)

---

More details about the ideas:

By basic ideas from the proof of the Artin-Wedderburn theorem, you can decompose $M$ into a direct sum of submodules which are "homogeneous." Explicitly, $M_S:=\oplus\{N<M\mid N\cong S\}$ where $S$ is a fixed simple submodule. Then $M=\oplus M_{S_k}$ for a representative set of simple submodules of $M$ $S_1,\dots S_n$.

Let's abbreviate $M_{S_k}$ to just $M_k$. Now if you look at $End_{F[G]}(M)$ through this decomposition, it takes the form of matrices of transformations whose $i,j$ entries are elements of $Hom(M_i,M_j)$. But it's easy to see that when $i\neq j$, the only homomorphism is zero, and so the only nonzero entries occur on the diagonal spots $Hom(M_i,M_i)$, which come from the endomorphism ring of $M_i$. So, $End_{F[G]}(M)=\oplus End_{F[G]}(M_i)$. If you show that each summand is semisimple, then you'll have shown the sum is semisimple.

Again, basic ideas of Artin-Wedderburn (or else you can skip them, if you already know them well) tell us that $End_{F[G]}(M_i)$ is isomorphic to $M_n(D)$ where $D=End(S_i)$ is a division ring and $S_i$ is the isotype of the simple submodules of $M_i$, and $n$ is the length of $M_i$. So, $End_{F[G]}(M_i)$ are all semisimple, and so is the sum of these rings.

Comment: This is a great answer.  Many thanks

Comment: I've reading your answer to Mark Rodriguez's question and I'm a bit confused about the last paragraph. I thought that $End_{F[G]}(M_i)$ is itself a division ring (say $D^i$), in fact a f.d. division algebra over $F$ and that $End_{D^i}(M_i)\cong M_{n_i}(D^i)$ where $n_i=$ dim$_{D^i}(M_i)$. So I'm not sure if your argument is correct. Am I missing something?

Comment: Dear @user68418 : The $M_i$ arent $F[G]$ simple, they are $F[G]$ semisimple, isomorphic to finitely many copies of a simple submodule $S$. $End_{F[G]}(S)=D$ is the division ring such that $End_{F[G]}(M)\cong M_n(D)$. (Or actually, if I transposed sides wrongly, there might be a missing $^{op}$ somewhere. If this doesn't clear things up, let me know.) Regards